# objective c mkmapview in UITapGestureRecognizer how can I test if they tapped on an annotation

Tags: ios, objective-c, mkmapview

I allow users to tap anywhere on the screen and I also allow them to tap on annotations to display text related to the annotation.

To allow them to tap anywhere on the screen I have setup a tapgesturerecoginzer.

The problem is that when they tap on an annotation, the tapgesturerecognizer event happens before the didSelectAnnotationView, and so I perform the tapgesturerecognizer when I do not want to.

Can I somehow test, in the tapgesturerecognizer, if they have tapped on an annotation ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution :

In my header (.h) I added the delegate:

```
@interface myVC : UIViewController <UIGestureRecognizerDelegate>
```

In .m :

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tap:)];
[self.mapView addGestureRecognizer:tap];
tap.delegate = self;
```

Note the delegate statement that Nirav said needed to be added

then I added Nirav's code but changed the IF statement :

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch
{
  if (([touch.view isKindOfClass:[MKPinAnnotationView class]]) || ([touch.view isKindOfClass:[MKAnnotationView class]]))
  {
    return NO;
  }
  return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have face the same issue with `LongGesture` you can use `UIGestureRecognizerDelegate` to prevent calling gesture action.

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch
{
    if ([touch.view isKindOfClass:[MKPinAnnotationView class]])
    {
        return NO;
    }
    return YES;
}
```

**Note:** Don't forgot to set delegate with your `tapGesture`.

Comment: Many thanks this put me on the right path but I had to add an additional test for MKAnnotationView for it to work as MKPinAnnotationView wasn't being recognised when I tapped the Annotation.  See expanded code below.